# Hidlibrary event threads

Tags: c#, events, hid

I'm using mikeobriens HIDLibrary for communicating with a sensor we make.

It's all working, and I have it so it re-enumerates if the device is unplugged then reconnected.

The problem I have is that each time it's reconnected, a new HidLibrary.HidDeviceEventMonitor.DeviceEventMonitor Worker Thread is created, and if the system is run like this for a long period, many threads are created. How can I kill these threads when the device is disconnected?

Comment: Take a time explain your situation ..post the code you'been tried ...what is expected ouput..

Comment: Jagadeesh, the code is as supplied in the HIDLibrary, unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a kind of bug if the HidLibrary.

If you look closer at the HidDevice class you may found that HidDevice.CloseDevice doesn't actually stop event monitoring.

There are two ways to fix it.
Either call Dispose instead of CloseDevice in your application:

```
//_device.CloseDevice(); - dispose will close device automatically
_device.Dispose();
```

Or set the flag MonitorDeviceEvents to false after CloseDevice call:

```
_device.CloseDevice();
_device.MonitorDeviceEvents = false;
```

I would prefer the first one.

N.B. Also be sure that you don't keep a reference to the disconnected device.

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me because I'm using the blocking call Device.ReadReport(AddressOf OnReport).  If I simply set the device to NULL (to get rid of the reference), then the next scan throws an exception.

To get around this, here's what I did:

```
Public Class myDevice
Private Device As HidDevice
Private isConnected as Boolean

Public Sub Close()
    If Not Device Is Nothing Then
        Device.CloseDevice()
        Device.MonitorDeviceEvents = False
    End If
    isConnected = False
End Sub

Sub OnReport(Report As HidReport)
    If isConnected = False Then
        Device.Dispose()
        Device = Nothing
        Return
    End If
    ' Do stuff with the data
    ' ...
    ' ...
    ' Wait for more data.
    Device.ReadReport(AddressOf OnReport)
End Sub
End Class
```

So after closing a device, the thread is left in a state where it is still waiting for input.  BUT ... I've set a flag to indicate that the device has been closed (Device.isConnected did not work for me, so I created my own flag).  The next event received by the closed thread detects that the device is no longer "connected", so it disposes the device, de-references the device, and returns **without calling ReadReport**.